# Windows explorer shows different results than using dir command

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer

I'm using "dir" to output the contents of a network drive to a text file for processing. The directory has ~135k files. When I search for a specific keyword in the windows explorer search box, I get 4 results.

When I do `dir <dir> | findstr /R /C:"keyword"` I get 8 results. The first set of results matches the timestamp and filesizes of what is displayed in windows explorer, but the next set of results show another timestamp and the same filesize. What could be the cause of this?

Also, the number of lines output in the dir command is the same as the number of files that shows in windows explorer.

Here is the output:

```
C:\Users\removed>dir "\\removed" | f
indstr /R /C:"keyword"
11/21/2013  12:54 PM            54,424  keyword.main.jpg
11/21/2013  12:54 PM            46,696  keyword.med.jpg
11/21/2013  12:54 PM            44,093  keyword.small.jpg
11/21/2013  12:53 PM            81,468  keyword.xl.jpg
11/21/2013  12:55 PM            54,424 keyword.main.jpg
11/21/2013  12:55 PM            46,696 keyword.med.jpg
11/21/2013  12:55 PM            44,093 keyword.small.jpg
11/21/2013  12:55 PM            81,468 keyword.xl.jpg
```

I'm using `preg_match_all('/\S+/', $line)` in PHP to separate these into columns.

Comment: What do you get if you do: dir *keyword*
Also wondering why you use /R if string you are searching for doesn't have any regex in it (or does "keyword" have reg ex in them.
Also is the space before the first 4 entries above a formatting issue... try search for *keyword in windows explorer search box

Comment: i found additional results with the *keyword search. that means that files contain a space at the beginning or what? that would explain the output.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was guessing. Does that answer what you were looking for?